# Lock according to formatting of the cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, formatting

I have a Spreadsheet with a conditional formatting (green color). The cell becomes green if someone write something in that cell.

I need if a cell turns green, it should lock automatically (except the editor:me)

And this script must "run" automatically every time that a cell becomes green.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your English is fine. Your question is not. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Also how can the user change the cell if it is locked as soon as he types something?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so the user can't modify the cell after the insertion of data in that cell. I can't post some scripts because my knowledge of programming is very low... but i really need something :)

Comment: So visit the many links I just gave you access to. They show you how

Comment: i tried to visit the two research, but nothing near my bad problem..